# Implementing a Runge-Kutta 4 method for 3 body problem in Python

Tags: python, differential-equations, gravity, runge-kutta

I'm trying to implement an RK4 method in Python to solve for the Sun, Earth and Jupiter system. This code works for Halley's comet, when I have 4 ODEs to solve instead of 8, I've tried extending my method to 8 ODEs but now I just keep getting a straight line and have no idea why. Can someone please point out to me the stupid mistake I'm making, because I'm stumped as to why this isn't working. Here's the code:

```
import math
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

G = 6.67e-11
M = 1.989e+30       #mass of the sun
m1 = 5.972e+24      #mass of planet 1
m2 = 1.898e+27      #mass of planet 2
AU = 1.496e+11
a1 = 1.0*AU         #distance from planet 1 to the sun
a2 = 5.2*AU         #distance from planet 2 to the sun

#A = -(G*M)/(a1**3)
#B = -(G*M)/(a2**3)
##C = G/(abs(a2 - a1)**3)
#
#print("A = ", A, "B = ", B)

x_i1 = a1               #initial values for planet 1 in x and y direction
y_i1 = 0.0
v_x1i = 0.0
v_y1i = 3e+4

x_i2 = a2               #initial values for planet 2 in x and y direction
y_i2 = 0.0
v_x2i = 0.0
v_y2i = 13.07e+3

t_upper = 365*24*3600   #run the program to simulate a year
t = 0.0
t_i = 0.0
N = 10000


def f1(r, t):       #function containing the relevant equations and arrays

    x1 = r[0]       #storing position and velocity components in x and y direction for planet 1
    y1 = r[2]
    v_x1 = r[1]
    v_y1 = r[3]

    x2 = r[4]       #storing position and vecloity components in x and y direction for planet 2
    y2 = r[6]
    v_x2 = r[5]
    v_y2 = r[7]

    C = G/(((x1 - x2)**2 + (y1 - y2)**2)**1.5)      #equations for 3 body problem, just to condense the maths
    D = G/(((x2 - x1)**2 + (y2 - y1)**2)**1.5)
    A = (G*M)/(a1**3)
    B = (G*M)/(a2**3)


    dvx1 = (A*x1) + ((C*m2)*(x1 - x2))      #Acceleration in x and y for each planet
    dvy1 = (A*y1) + ((C*m2)*(y1 - y2))    
    dvx2 = (B*x2) - ((D*m1)*(x2 - x1))
    dvy2 = (B*y2) - ((D*m1)*(y2 - y1))

    return np.array([v_x1, dvx1, v_y1, dvy1, v_x2, dvx2, v_y2, dvy2]) #return array storing all the differential equations we want to solve



r = np.array([x_i1, v_x1i, y_i1, v_y1i, x_i2, v_x2i, y_i2, v_y2i], float) #define array with initial values


x_pnts1 = [x_i1]                #array containing the position in x for planet 1                 
v_x_pnts1 = [v_x1i]             #array containing the velocity in x for planet 1
y_pnts1 = [y_i1]                #position in y for planet 1
v_y_pnts1 = [v_y1i]             #velocity in y for planet 1

x_pnts2 = [x_i2]                #same as above, but for planet 2                 
v_x_pnts2 = [v_x2i]
y_pnts2 = [y_i2]
v_y_pnts2 = [v_y2i]

t_values = [t_i]

h = t_upper/N

while t < t_upper:

    k1 = h*f1(r, t)                 #RK4 routine, using the function defined above
    k2 = h*f1(r + 0.5*k1, t+h/2)
    k3 = h*f1(r + 0.5*k2, t+h/2)
    k4 = h*f1(r + k3, t+h)

    r += (k1 + 2*k2 + 2*k3 + k4)/6


    x_pnts1.append(r[0])     #append the relevant arrays with the values from the RK4 routine
    v_x_pnts1.append(r[1])
    y_pnts1.append(r[2])
    v_y_pnts1.append(r[3])

    x_pnts2.append(r[4])     
    v_x_pnts2.append(r[5])
    y_pnts2.append(r[6])
    v_y_pnts2.append(r[7])

    t += h    

    t_values.append(t)


aphelion_e = np.max(x_pnts1)
perihelion_e = abs(np.min(x_pnts1))

print("Perihelion of earth = ", perihelion_e/AU, "AU")
print("Aphelion of earth = ", aphelion_e/AU, "AU")

plt.plot(x_pnts1, y_pnts1)
plt.plot(0, 0, "o", 15)
plt.show()
```

Comment: a1, a2 are also dynamical quantities, you need to recompute them in the derivatives function to get a correct force.

Comment: You also need to carefully check the forces, gravity is always attracting, never repelling as you encoded in 3/4 of the signs.